# GETDATE() Function SQL Server 2008 R2 has difference with windows server time

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008

I have Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I get date with `SELECT GETDATE()` from SQL Server, it shows the current date and time, but with 6 minutes less than Windows server watch (time) .

I checked location, time and Active Directory but I don't understand why my SQL Server `GetDate` function returns 6 minutes difference compared to my Windows server time.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Shouldn't be possible. Are you sure, 100% sure, that the server that you're asking to run `GETDATE()` and the server where you're examining the local clock are the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SSMS run this statement:

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBios') ComputerNamePhysicalNetBios,GETDATE() DateTime
```

Then RDP to this machine and make sure time displayed is same as displayed in SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution at  Active Directory setting and master server that databases placed on . 
problem may be from below items :

Getting group policy updates and may have issues authenticating
(but that can be fixed with a time reset and reboot)

will have to:   sync time to a nonexistent timesource see Windows Time Service Tools and Settings ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773263%28WS.10%29.aspx)

this will prevent the domain from automatically repairing the time , 
change the time manually.

and read other best link be in below :

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/configure-a-time-server-for-active-directory-domain-controllers/3690

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28v=ws.10%29.aspx